# minimum resource requirements for a TLS handshake

Tags: tls, embedded-system

What are the minimum resource requirements to to a TLS handshake? Is it possible to do a full TLS handshake on very low powered devices? Are there any sources on this? Can TLS be configured in some way to reduce the resource requirements?

Comment: You need to define your spec more. Do you want to accept all cipher suites or just a few? How robust do you want it? Have you looked at the light-weight TLS implementations for embedded systems to see if they meet your needs?

Comment: You want to look at https://bearssl.org/ it is the best TLS stack for embedded devices (works for ARM cortex M0). You should carefully choose the cipher suite you want to use, and not try to support many cipher suites.

Comment: I'm looking for what the theoretical minimum is. For example: Is it possible to create a TLS connection on a 16-bit processor?

Comment: I'm just going to go ahead and speculate that the certificate chain validation is one of the most expensive operations. But we could use PSK cipher suites to reduce that. Are there any other things we could do? Without sacrificing too much security.

Comment: PSK would be cheaper, but nobody uses PSK. Author of bearssl explains that in TLS 1.2 embedded devices can use cheap static-static Diffie Hellman, no longer allowed in TLS 1.3: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67214/24949 so I guess you can do TLS 1.2 static-static Diffie Hellman over Curve25519 (the fastest) and that can be implemented on 16bit and even 8bit CPU. Performance mostly depends on hardware multiplier (16bit x 16bit -> 32bit result, smaller or large multiplier available?). Cortex M0+ can do such handshake in a second. If your 16bit chip can do it in 30 seconds, you're fine.

Comment: A bearssl client that supports only TLS1.2 TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (w/ P256 and known public key) is about 22KB of code, and needs about 6KB of RAM + 22KB of RAM per connection. It works on esp8266: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/bearssl-client-secure-class.html maybe you can port it to your 16bit chip.

Comment: @Z.T. I use PSK . I was wondering how large the savings from using it over certs is. Is there any data on that? What exactly do you mean be "static-static DH"? How exactly does it help with resource usage?

Comment: See link to crypto SE in my comment above. What kind of "resource"? Time to handshake? Code size? RAM use while handshaking? Using PSK you don't do asymmetric crypto (verifying RSA or ECDSA signature, ECDHE key exchange, or ECDH if static-static), so you get savings in all of them, though savings in RAM are less significant.